# New to sql could someone walk me through this query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got homework to write the following query: "Write an SQL query to print the name of employees having the highest salary in each department". My understanding is still not good enough to write this query. I found where the lecturer copied the homework as well as the answer but unfortunately, I do not fully understand what is wrong. I would appreciate it if someone could walk me through the logic behind this query:

https://www.techbeamers.com/sql-query-questions-answers-for-practice/

```
SELECT t.DEPARTMENT,t.FIRST_NAME,t.Salary 
from(SELECT max(Salary) as TotalSalary,DEPARTMENT 
from Worker
group by DEPARTMENT) as TempNew 
Inner Join Worker t on TempNew.DEPARTMENT=t.DEPARTMENT and TempNew.TotalSalary=t.Salary;
```

Comment: The best way to learn is by doing. Create some fake data if you do not have some already and start *executing* your query against it. What is returned? Is there an error? Observe the results, adjust the query based on your findings, and try again. This is how you become a developer, trail and error and hopefully learning from each experience.

Comment: To expand on Igor's comment, the best  way to start is by cutting the problem in smaller pieces (which is still a large part of my job), once you know the smaller problems, programming them becomes simple. What do you want to know? "The highest salary in each department", so write a query to calculate that. Next, "who earned those highest salaries". Joining the calculated highest back to the table is easy (since they probably only earn one salary, at least per department).

Comment: @HoneyBadger could you perhaps just guide me in the right direction the most confusing part is where is t.column_name coming from what must I do research about.

Answer (score 0):

Basically: The example only works as long as there aren't two people that have the same highest salary. As long as this is true:

Let's start with the INNERMOST sub-query:

```
SELECT max(Salary) as TotalSalary,DEPARTMENT 
from Worker
group by DEPARTMENT
```

This basically takes all data from the Worker table and selects the highest Salary for each DEPARTMENT. The result is a table with one row per non-empty department with the department's name and highest salary.

For the rest of the query, this intermediary result as being alias with TempNew.

Next part is the join:

```
Inner Join Worker t on TempNew.DEPARTMENT=t.DEPARTMENT and TempNew.TotalSalary=t.Salary
```

So, we are now joining that intermediary result with the original Worker table, which, in this query is now aliased as t. We join on DEPARTMENT and TotalSalary = t.Salary.

This means: For each row in TempNew, we fetch all rows that have the same DEPARTMENT and where Salary is TotalSalary. Assuming, that we do not have any duplicate salaries, this will return exactly one row from t for each row of TempNew.

Finally, the select:

```
SELECT t.DEPARTMENT,t.FIRST_NAME,t.Salary
```

So, from the above joined up data, we are now selecting the columns DEPARTMENT, FIRST_NAME and Salary of the alias t (which is the original Worker table "filtered" by TempNew).

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: thank you very much I did not realise you could select something by an alias if you only declare it as that alias later in the query. My understanding of aliases clearly needs work but we never covered it in class so ill have to go do some studying.